# JSON Load data into a list

Tags: json, get, load, embed

I have following json structure - it is a restaurant list with its geo co-ordinates.

```
{"Pizza Dach": {
"Kategorie": "Swabian",
"Position": {
    "Longitude": 9.307256,
    "Latitude": 48.741518
}
},
"Galeria Zeus": {
"Kategorie": "Greek",
"Position": {
    "Longitude": 9.303788,
    "Latitude": 48.74131
    }
}
}
```

And now I want to embed this list into my app, based on jquery and jquery mobile. So I have a Section where this list should be shown.

```
 <div data-role="page" id="restaurants"> 
<header data-role="header">
<h1>restaurants</h1>
</header> 
<article data-role="content">
            <ul>
            <!-- CONTENT WILL BE FILLED IN HERE DYNAMICALLY -->
            </ul>
        </article>
    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<nav data-role="navbar">
 <ul>
            <li><a class="karte" href="#karte">Karte</a></li>
            <li><a class="uebersicht" href="#restaurants">Liste</a></li>
            <li><a class="optionen" href="#optionen">Optionen</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</footer>
    </div>
```

So can maybe anybody help me with the json command for this structure?  I don't get the whole syntax and do not know what li id and which key I should fill in.

```
$.getJSON( "data/restaurants.json", function( data ) {
var items = [];
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
});
$( "<ul/>", {
"class": "my-new-list",
html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "#restaurants" );
});
```

Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mustache.js library](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) to *render* the data.You just have to get an object (from JSON) and create appropriate template (to render it).